# Placing Labels programmatically over an ImageView

Tags: android, xamarin, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm making an app to solve sudokus, so in the app I'm using an Imageview that displays an empty 9x9 grid which I've placed within a relative layout. I'm trying to create the interface programmatically, so what I want to know is how can I places labels on top of the Imageview so that they match the locations of the squares of the grid. I know that the labels can be on top of Imageview, but just not how to get them into place. Does Xamarin provide a way to accomplish this as all I've found is how to use alignment methods with the relative layout.

Here's code my so far:

```
public class GridActivity : Activity
{
    // Global Variables
    Button startButton;
    Button nextButton;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams startButtonParamsPortrait;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams startButtonParamsLandscape;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams nextButtonParamsPortrait;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams nextButtonParamsLandscape;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Don't want the action bar to show, find it unnecessary, so gonna hide it.
        ActionBar.Hide();

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        // get the initial orientation
        var surfaceOrientation = WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation;

        RelativeLayout layoutBase = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layoutBase.LayoutParameters = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        layoutBase.SetPadding(100, 100, 100, 100);

        // Adding a Imageview to display the sudoku grid
        ImageView grid = new ImageView(this);
        grid.LayoutParameters = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        grid.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        grid.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.SudokuGrid);
        grid.Id = 1;
        layoutBase.AddView(grid);

        // Adding a button that will be used to step through the "AI"'s solution
        nextButton = new Button(this) { Text = "Next" };
        nextButton.Id = 2;

        // Adding a button that will be used to start the "AI" to solve the puzzle
        startButton = new Button(this) { Text = "Start" };
        startButton.Id = 3;

        // Layout Parameters for Portrait mode
        // nextButton
        nextButtonParamsPortrait = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        nextButtonParamsPortrait.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom);
        nextButtonParamsPortrait.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentRight);
        // startButton
        startButtonParamsPortrait = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        startButtonParamsPortrait.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom);
        startButtonParamsPortrait.AddRule(LayoutRules.LeftOf, nextButton.Id);

        // Layout Parameters for Landscape mode
        // startButton
        startButtonParamsLandscape = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        startButtonParamsLandscape.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentRight);
        // nextButton
        nextButtonParamsLandscape = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        nextButtonParamsLandscape.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentRight);
        nextButtonParamsLandscape.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, startButton.Id);

        // Add labels in the location of the squares 

        // Depending on the initial orientation, the buttons will placed at different locations
        if (surfaceOrientation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0 || surfaceOrientation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation180)
        {
            // The screen is in Portrait mode
            startButton.LayoutParameters = startButtonParamsPortrait;
            nextButton.LayoutParameters = nextButtonParamsPortrait;
        }
        else
        {
            // The screen is in Landscape mode
            startButton.LayoutParameters = startButtonParamsLandscape;
            nextButton.LayoutParameters = nextButtonParamsLandscape;
        }

        // Add the buttons to the layout
        layoutBase.AddView(startButton);
        layoutBase.AddView(nextButton);

        // Display the layout to the screen
        SetContentView(layoutBase);            
    }

    public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Portrait)
        {
            startButton.LayoutParameters = startButtonParamsPortrait;
            nextButton.LayoutParameters = nextButtonParamsPortrait;
        }
        else if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape)
        {
            startButton.LayoutParameters = startButtonParamsLandscape;
            nextButton.LayoutParameters = nextButtonParamsLandscape;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the labels? Can you accomplish the same thing by changing the image in the ImageView?

Comment: The purpose of the labels is going to display numbers for the sudoku, they will also have a clicked method which will display a "picker" to allow the user to select a number between 1-9 in order to set up the puzzle for the app to solve. I don't want to use text view as they don't give the flat text look I'm going for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Absolute layout to position label over other children (your grid) of the layout (has to be older child).

Comment: I look into this layout later today when I have more free time. I'm assuming the relative layout doesn't have a way to do this and that is why you are suggesting this layout.

Comment: you might also have a look at the discussion about pros and cons of both - examples could give you an idea how to do it with relative too  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17742/relativelayout-in-xaml

Answer (score -2):

you can use [framelayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) to achieve this.

Below is simple layout to for same.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView 
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"  
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"
   android:layout_height="250px"
   android:layout_width="250px"/>
<TextView
   android:text="Frame Demo"
   android:textSize="30px"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

you can also add same TextView in Programmatically.

[image]